# Load data from database SQLite in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Do you know any tutorial that tells me how can read the data from sqlite database SQLite and put them in a table?

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a problem that is explained in another question where not responds anyone to three days and I do not know to solve, is the first time that I use SQLite, and I can not ask any of my colleagues in my office

Comment: If nobody answered your first question this is probably because your question was not well formulated. Try to better describe what your problem is and what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[i think you should try this one, hope this helps](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

[and here's one more](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app)

There are a bunch of tutorials dedicated working with Core Data and SQLite on that site, i believe it may help

Comment: Please don't post only a link. Describe why you think the link answers the question.

Comment: The question is pretty simple. The guy just asks for a tutorial, so i'm pretty sure the link is enough to help, it's difficult to add something else

Comment: I want to thank Andrey Chernukha for link